# What's the HTML tag that doesn't process HTML inside of it?

Tags: html

Google fail, I used to know what it was years ago...

Basically would make `<theTag><img src='cat.jpg'/></theTag>` render as `<img src='cat.jpg'/>` rather than actually displaying the image...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tag is `<xmp>`, but it's deprecated.

A better way to go is to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively. Also, `&` with `&amp;`, and you should be perfectly safe.

Comment: Well, it was over 10 years ago that I learned it ;D Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It was deprecated in 1997 (if not before).

Comment: @SLC: At least you've forgot about it and moved on. I don't know how the rest of us can defend remembering stuff that hasn't been approved of since before HTML 4 =)

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for the <xmp> tag but that is nowhere near valid HTML anymore :)

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#xmp

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably talking about CDATA sections?

```
<![CDATA[<img src='cat.jpg'/>]]>
```

Be careful though, this doesn’t work very well in some browsers. Plus, <del>I *think* it doesn’t exist in HTML, only in XML</del>. [It exists in HTML](http://www.flightlab.com/~joe/sgml/cdata.html) but browser support is not reliable. It’s better to just escape everything.

Comment: @Matthew: yes, I believe that as well but I wasn’t sure.

Comment: CDATA marked sections are part of SGML and thus part of HTML too — it's just that nothing supports it.

Answer (score 0):

What about `<pre>`? As far as I understand it's made exactly for these cases.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It preserves formatting (such as multiple spaces), but it doesn't ignore HTML tags.

Comment: To get `<span>this is a span</span>` within a `<pre>` you need this: 
`<pre>&lt;span&gt;this is a span&lt;/span&gt;</pre>`

Comment: oh, o.k. then I have been misusing it :) Thanks for the info.